# Como colocar as tabuada lado a lado?

Tags: python

Queria fazer as tabuadas de 1 a 10, onde estas apareçam lado a lado. Para já tenho este código em que o resultado aparece para baixo:

```
for j in range(1,11):
 print("Tabuada do %d:" % j)
 for i in range(1,11):
  print("%dx%d=%d" % (j, i , j*i))
```

Objetivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria [isso](https://bit.ly/3OzIHmc)?

Answer (score -2):

De modo simples, o `end=''` resolveria.

```
for j in range(1,11):
    print("Tabuada do %d:" % j)
    for i in range(1,11):
        print("%dx%d=%d " % (j, i , j*i), end='')
    print()
```

**Nota 1** O `print()` vazio é para finalmente saltar linha.

**Nota 2** O espaço após a impressão da conta serve para deixar as contas separadas.

Porém, sugiro olhar a documentação sobre [formatação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#)

### Atualizado em 21/06/2022

De acordo com a `melhor especificação do objetivo` feita pelo autor do post segue solução colocando resposta em colunas:

```
estrutura = {}

for i in range(1,11):
    chave = f"Tabuada do {i}"
    estrutura[chave] = []
    for j in range(1,11):
        estrutura[chave].append(f"{i} x {j} = {i * j}")


# Cabeçalho
for t in estrutura:
    print(f"{t:<15}", end='')
print()


# Tabuadas
for contador in range(0, 10):
    for t in estrutura:
        print(f"{estrutura[t][contador]:<15}", end='')
    print()
```

Resultado

```
Tabuada do 1   Tabuada do 2   Tabuada do 3   Tabuada do 4   Tabuada do 5   Tabuada do 6   Tabuada do 7   Tabuada do 8   Tabuada do 9   Tabuada do 10
1 x 1 = 1      2 x 1 = 2      3 x 1 = 3      4 x 1 = 4      5 x 1 = 5      6 x 1 = 6      7 x 1 = 7      8 x 1 = 8      9 x 1 = 9      10 x 1 = 10
1 x 2 = 2      2 x 2 = 4      3 x 2 = 6      4 x 2 = 8      5 x 2 = 10     6 x 2 = 12     7 x 2 = 14     8 x 2 = 16     9 x 2 = 18     10 x 2 = 20
1 x 3 = 3      2 x 3 = 6      3 x 3 = 9      4 x 3 = 12     5 x 3 = 15     6 x 3 = 18     7 x 3 = 21     8 x 3 = 24     9 x 3 = 27     10 x 3 = 30
1 x 4 = 4      2 x 4 = 8      3 x 4 = 12     4 x 4 = 16     5 x 4 = 20     6 x 4 = 24     7 x 4 = 28     8 x 4 = 32     9 x 4 = 36     10 x 4 = 40
1 x 5 = 5      2 x 5 = 10     3 x 5 = 15     4 x 5 = 20     5 x 5 = 25     6 x 5 = 30     7 x 5 = 35     8 x 5 = 40     9 x 5 = 45     10 x 5 = 50
1 x 6 = 6      2 x 6 = 12     3 x 6 = 18     4 x 6 = 24     5 x 6 = 30     6 x 6 = 36     7 x 6 = 42     8 x 6 = 48     9 x 6 = 54     10 x 6 = 60
1 x 7 = 7      2 x 7 = 14     3 x 7 = 21     4 x 7 = 28     5 x 7 = 35     6 x 7 = 42     7 x 7 = 49     8 x 7 = 56     9 x 7 = 63     10 x 7 = 70
1 x 8 = 8      2 x 8 = 16     3 x 8 = 24     4 x 8 = 32     5 x 8 = 40     6 x 8 = 48     7 x 8 = 56     8 x 8 = 64     9 x 8 = 72     10 x 8 = 80
1 x 9 = 9      2 x 9 = 18     3 x 9 = 27     4 x 9 = 36     5 x 9 = 45     6 x 9 = 54     7 x 9 = 63     8 x 9 = 72     9 x 9 = 81     10 x 9 = 90
1 x 10 = 10    2 x 10 = 20    3 x 10 = 30    4 x 10 = 40    5 x 10 = 50    6 x 10 = 60    7 x 10 = 70    8 x 10 = 80    9 x 10 = 90    10 x 10 = 100
```

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, favor informar o motivo para que eu melhore a resposta.

Comment: Especifiquei melhor o objetivo, obrigado!